# Where clause inside select with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Have 6 tables

**tours_atp** (_wta - the same)

**players_atp** (_wta - the same)
[image]

**games_atp** (_wta - the same)

[image]

With tours_atp + games_atp join everything OK, but how i can join (or inside select) players table for recieve columns with players names inside, something like this

```
ID1_G, ID2_G, player1, player2, id_t.....
```

I try to select inside join

```
SELECT DISTINCT `ID_T_G` AS `id_t`, `NAME_T` AS `name`, `DATE_G`, `RESULT_G`, `DATE_T`, `COUNTRY_T`, `ID1_G`, `ID2_G`, `ID_R_G`,
  (SELECT CONCAT(`NAME`, ' ', `LASTNAME`) AS player1 FROM players_ru_atp WHERE games_atp.ID1_G = players_ru_atp.ID_P) AS `player1`,
  (SELECT CONCAT(`NAME`, ' ', `LASTNAME`) AS player2 FROM players_ru_atp WHERE games_atp.ID2_G = players_ru_atp.ID_P) AS `player2`
FROM `games_atp` LEFT JOIN `tours_atp` ON tours_atp.ID_T = games_atp.ID_T_G
WHERE (`DATE_G` BETWEEN '2018-06-29' AND '2018-06-29')
      AND (`player1` LIKE '%John Doe%') GROUP BY `ID_T_G`;
```

but `Unknown column 'player1' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Always qualify all column names in your query.

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.

Comment: And what's the purpose of `GROUP BY` if you don't have any aggregation???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  But your `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `ID_T_G` AS `id_t`
    , `NAME_T` AS `name`
    , `DATE_G`, `RESULT_G`
    , `DATE_T`, `COUNTRY_T`
    , `ID1_G`, `ID2_G`
    , `ID_R_G`
    , (SELECT CONCAT(`NAME`, ' ', `LASTNAME`) AS player1 FROM players_ru_atp WHERE games_atp.ID1_G = players_ru_atp.ID_P) AS `player1`
    , (SELECT CONCAT(`NAME`, ' ', `LASTNAME`) AS player2 FROM players_ru_atp WHERE games_atp.ID2_G = players_ru_atp.ID_P) AS `player2`
FROM `games_atp` 
LEFT JOIN `tours_atp` ON tours_atp.ID_T = games_atp.ID_T_G
WHERE `DATE_G` BETWEEN '2018-06-29' AND '2018-06-29'
      AND (SELECT CONCAT(`NAME`, ' ', `LASTNAME`) AS player1 FROM players_ru_atp WHERE games_atp.ID1_G = players_ru_atp.ID_P) LIKE '%John Doe%'
GROUP BY `ID_T_G`;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Sorry, group by is removed now, forgot about it (use it when calculating rates in previous version of query)